# Static library and header chaining issues

Tags: ios, c, xcode, static-libraries

I have three projects in XCode.

- ProjectA, a pure C project
- ProjectB, a objective C project
- ProjectC, a mix of objective C and Swift

ProjectA is a static library project used in ProjectB.
Header files from projectA are in copy file target, it is in ProjectB\lib\ProjectA.a and \lib\include folder.

ProjectB is linked as a sub project in ProjectC.

ProjectC imports some header file from ProjectB.
Those header files in ProjetB have imported header files in ProjectA.

My problem is, ProjectA is not visible in ProjectC. ProjectC compilation fails since ProjectC imports headers from ProjectB and B has header files imported from projectA.

What is the way to solve this C->A dependency on .h files?

### In ProjectA.

file DesTypes.h:
// some types are defined here.

### In ProjectB.

ProjectA.a is linked as static lib.

File CryptoUtil.h :

```
#import DesTypes.h
```

// some function prototypes used types from Destypes. The .h is in search header path. So no problem.
I need the import here since some function prototype uses the types from DesTypes.h.
Otherwise importing DesTypes.h in CryptoUtil.m file would solve the problem.

### In ProjectC

File MyViewController.h:

```
#import CryptoUtli.h
// Here I get compile error for chaining. I do not use anything from DesType.h.
```

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane: How do you propose doing that? This is a question about Xcode project structure and settings, not about the C language. The project structure and settings are usually displayed in the GUI. They are recorded in a technically human-readable form in the .xcodeproj file, but that is not by any means the preferred form for working with a project.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't know - it wasn't my question. I put that because all I can see is a narrative with ProjectA, B, C etc. which reads as if the question could be "who ate the apple?" And I put it before I noticed the asker's rep.

Comment: @EricPostpischil agree, but the c tag should be removed if it doesn't have to do with C at all. It seems, it's a questions of "how do I use this software correctly".

Comment: re-architecture? In ProjectB, can you move all the ProjectA `#include`s to a separate dedicated header file? Then in ProjectC when you `#include` ProjectB stuff, don't include the new file and you won't see any of the ProjectA stuff. If you can't do that then it seems that ProjectC is dependent on ProjectA, and perhaps ProjectA should be visible to ProjectC.

Comment: I try to explain more in the description.

Comment: Can you copy the needed files from A to the B build output where C can pick it up?

Comment: Since it is not directly used in C, I am not eager to do it. But that's the only possible solution right now.